# Call instance of class in Xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Help me understand.
I create template of SilverlightApplication1 in VS2012. Create in my solution folder Models and add class EmployeeTypes.cs. I need to call up the instance of EmployeeTypes.cs in Xaml file (Home.xaml).

I do so in Home.xaml:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Home" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.Models" 
                           ....
                           ....
```

Then i do so ( all this according tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2012/04/09/silverlight-tree-view-with-multiple-levels.aspx):

```
<local:EmployeeTypes x:Key=" employeeTemplate"/>
```

Here VS2012 says: 'local:EmployeeTypes' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Where i am wrong???

**EmployeeTypes.cs**

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1.Models
{
public class EmpolyeeTypes : List<EmployeeType>
{
    public EmpolyeeTypes()
    {
    EmployeeType type;
    type=new EmployeeType("Manager");
    type.Employees.Add(new Employee("Michael"));
    type.Employees.Add(new Employee("Paul"));
    this.Add(type);

    type = new EmployeeType("Project Managers");
    type.Employees.Add(new Employee("Tim"));
    type.Employees.Add(new Employee("John"));
    type.Employees.Add(new Employee("David"));
    this.Add(type);

    }


}
```

}

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Home" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.Models"      
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"             
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
Title="Home"
Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">
<local:EmployeeTypes x:Key=" employeeTemplate"/>
        .......
        .......


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

</Grid>
```

Comment: Just guessing, does your EmployeeTypes class have a default parameterless constructor?

Comment: I added file! Constuctor without parameters.

Comment: where you put this code : `<local:EmployeeTypes x:Key=" employeeTemplate"/>` ?

Comment: I looks like you had a typo in your code: 
EmpolyeeTypes != local:EmployeeTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move it to `Resources` of one UI control, for example as `Resources` of `Grid` :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:EmployeeTypes x:Key=" employeeTemplate"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

or as `Resources` of the page :

```
<navigation:Page 
    ......
    >
    <navigation:Page.Resources>
        <local:EmployeeTypes x:Key=" employeeTemplate"/>
    </navigation:Page.Resources>
</navigation:Page>
```

PS: my answer came from Windows Phone and WPF background, could be different in silverlight. Not sure.

Comment: It worked! Wow! Now I need to understand why it is necessary to do so

Comment: generally speaking, XAML is where you put UI control (something that visible to user). And in this case you want to put an object (any object, can be instance of a UI control too) that doesn't meant to be shown to user just like that. It must go under `Resources`, and you can access it later by referencing it's `Key`.

Comment: check this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case my explanation is not good enough.

Comment: one more, simple explanation is, that is syntax for resources content : `<Namespace:className x:Key="resourceKey"/>`